# Error al enviar una petición por cada letra que escribo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]    `

Debo hacer la peticion al backen de email y pass y guardar el token, mas al querer llenar los datos me envia esos errorres por cada letra que digito como se ve en la img antes de siquiera llenar el formulario, alguien tiene alguna idea del xq pasa eso y como lo

`

Comment: Con "peticiones sin control" a que te refieres? hay un ciclo infinito de peticiones?, no es clara tu pregunta, en consola muestra  un sin fin de errores que puede ser de distintas causas, ese pequeño fragmento de codigo que has insertado practicamente es inútil para poder llegar a una solución. Lee [ask] y [example], recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta para agregar más detalles.

Comment: Me refiero a que envia esas peticiones post apenas empiezo a llenar los campos para hacer login

Comment: @DarioCuray ... por favor lee [ask] antes de continuar... luego, pega el código relevante, sin código no podemos ayudarte

Comment: Gracias, ya di con el problema estado enviando un try catch demas ,la proxima tomare en cuenta esos errores al publicar el problema